# Where can I find a List class for javascript with add() remove() and contains()?

Tags: javascript

Where can I find a List class for javascript with add(obj) remove(obj) and contains(obj)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can already use push instead of add and pop instead of remove.

[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/301816) contains an answer for how to do contains.

Answer (score 2):

You could write some simple array extensions:

```
Array.prototype.add = function (obj) {
    if (this && this.length)
       this.push(obj);
};

[1, 2, 3].add(4);
```

... etc

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't hard features to implement. I would simply create my own custom type that inherited from Array and added the two additional methods you'd like (since you can already use `push` to add items).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the native javascript's arrays

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(5); // add(obj)
arr.indexOf(5); // returns the index in the array or -1 if not found -> contains(obj)
```

For removing, you can use `arr.pop()` to remove last element or `arr.shift()` to remove the first element.

More on javascript's arrays - http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Comment: +1 for answer.  Wish I could give another +1 for that link.  Thanks!